# How to check for dot(.) in mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect URL

```
domain/Family_He..
```

to

```
domain/Family_Health_insurance
```

using RewriteRule. I have tried with

```
RewriteRule /Family_He(.*)$ /Family_Health_insurance
```

and it is working. But I have some more page with urls like

```
domain/Family_Health_info
domain/Family_Health_quote
domain/Family_Health_child etc
```

When I tried as

```
RewriteRule /Family_He\.\.$ /Family_Health_insurance
```

then this won't works for me. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that there are actually two spaces at the end of your subject string that would prevent `\.$` (a literal dot at the end of the string) from matching?

Comment: No, I am not aware of this. What can I do in this scenario to work this?

Comment: I'm just looking at the string you included in your question. If the string you're trying to match ends with two dots followed by two spaces, I'd try something like `/Family_He\.\.\s\s$`.

Comment: Or if you are a nitpicker, and only want to match spaces `/Family_He\.\.\ \ $` :-)

Answer (score 0):

To have it redirect (302) you need to add the `R` flag. To match the dot you need to escape it using `\.` like

```
RewriteRule ^/Family_He\.\.$ /Family_Health_insurance [R=302,L]
```

Note that the leading slash doesn't work in htaccess, only in httpd.conf

Comment: You can use `[.]` where you would use `\.`; that can be more readable in some circumstances.

Comment: @DonalFellows I'll see your `[.]` and raise you `[.]{2}` :-P

Comment: Meh; that's ugly and no advantage over doubling up `[.]` normally.